# Storing hierarchical data in Google Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have data in the following structure:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "A Title",
  "description": "A description.",

  "listOfStrings": ["one", "two", "three"]

  "keyA": {
    "keyB": " ",
    "keyC": " ",
    "keyD": {
      "keyE": " ",
      "KeyF": " "
    }
  } 
}
```

I want to put/get this in Google Datastore. What is the best way to store this?

Should I be using entity groups?

Requirements:

- I do not need transactions.
- Must be performant to read the whole structure.
- Must be able to query based on KeyEs content.

This link ([Storing hierarchical data in Google App Engine Datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011814/storing-hierarchical-data-in-google-app-engine-datastore)) mentions using entity groups for hierarchical data, but this link ([How to get all the descendants of a given instance of a model in google app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515132/how-to-get-all-the-descendants-of-a-given-instance-of-a-model-in-google-app-engi)) mentions they should only be used for transactions, which I do not need.

Im using this library (which I do not think supports ReferenceProperty?).
http://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-ruby.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to query by the hierarchy (keyA->keyB->keyC) -- use ancestors, or just a key which will look like this to avoid entity group limits. If you want to be able to query an entity which contains provided key -- make a computed property where you will store a flat list of keys stored inside. And store the original hierarchy in the JsonProeprty for example.

Comment: So you and @BrentWashburne are suggesting:
Flatten the hierarchy. _"keyA[keyD][keyE]" = " "_
Or/And store it as a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the more entities you request the slower (less performant) it becomes.  Making lots of entities with small bits of data is not efficient.  Instead, store the whole hierarchy as a JsonProperty and use code to walk through it.

If KeyE is just a string, then add a property `KeyE = StringProperty(indexed=True)` so you can query against it.